# Hadoop namenode does not listen outside IPs

Tags: java, hadoop, networking, hdfs, firewall

I have a simple hadoop cluster of 3 machines. One master and two slaves. All of them are running the latest minimalist version of CentOS I downloaded [there](https://www.centos.org/download/).

All my machines have the same hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.56.101  master
192.168.56.102  slave1
192.168.56.103  slave2
```

The core-site.xml file is configured as follows: (The namenode should listen on port 9000)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:9000/</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

When starting hdfs from the master and checking the logs of the datanodes/slaves **I noticed the datanodes could not connect to the namenode**.

```
Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.56.101:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
```

**After further checking it looks like the port 9000 is only accessible if I attempt to connect to it from the namenode itself.**

```
[root@HadoopMaster conf]# sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :9000
tcp6       0      0 192.168.56.101:9000     :::*                    LISTEN      11055/java
```

Attempting a `telnet master 9000` only succeeds from the master host. The slaves get the following error:

```
[root@Slave1 logs]# telnet master 9000
Trying 192.168.56.101...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.56.101: No route to host
```

But on the contrary they can connect to port 22 just fine

```
[root@Slave1 logs]# telnet master 22
Trying 192.168.56.101...
Connected to master.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
```

**So this has to be an IP binding issue**.
I have looked everywhere and could not find a viable answer. Similar questions to mine were solved by using a fully qualified domain name in the `core-site.xml` file which I did without success.

By the way, I also disabled iptables and before that opened all my master's ports to my slaves IPs. No success.

If you find the answer, I would definitely like to send you a delicious virtual cookie ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized CentOS's default firewall is not iptables but firewalld.
After configuring this firewall correctly I managed to solve my problem!

Why is iptables installed but not used, that is a mystery though.
Boy, I prefer so much the Debian family.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running those VM in several instances of VM VirtualBox that seems natural, even if they are on the same network they can't see each other.

Check [virtualbox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) to configure the network properly, you can also check this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/119732/how-to-do-networking-between-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox)

Comment: My network configuration is fine. Each VM has a different IP in a host only network. And I have a NAT interface as well for the Internet access through my real computer. It is just hadoop that starts a service with a wrong up binding.